# <th align'"center"> not working on a bootstrap table. What might be the reason?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap hover table and I'm trying to align the column headers to the middle by using `<th align="center">`. This seems to have no effect on the table whatsoever, but `<td align="center">` works properly.

This is my code:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Score</th>
        <th align="center">Product</th>    #This line is not working
        <th>Who Reviewed</th>
        <th>When</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for review in object_list %}
        <tr>
            <td><a href="{% url 'backend_reviews_edit' review.pk %}">{{review.title}}</a></td>
            <td align="center">{{ review.score }}</td>
            <td align="center">{{ review.product.title }}</td>
            <td>{{ review.reviewer_name}}</td>
            <td>{{ review.date_created|date:"m-d-Y" }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
    </div>
```

Comment: Alignment should be handled by CSS, not HTML.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

If you're using bootstrap, use its CSS rules.

```
<th class="text-center">Product</th>
```

Comment: Yup, that does it, but should I use this for <td> as well, because it seems to work without a class

Comment: As I mentioned, alignment (and all other presentation) should not be done with HTML, it should be done with CSS. `align` is deprecated.

Comment: To make it apply to both th or td....just apply it to tr. What is inside of each row inherits the property.

Answer (score 19):

Use this

```
<th class="text-center">Product</th>
```

attribute align not work because on bootstrap stylesheet find this:

```
th {
    text-align:left
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Or this may be tried out.

```html
<th style="text-align:center">Product</th>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

If the none of the above work, you can try

`style="text-align:center !important"`

I had same problem center aligning in a Vuetify table and that fixed it.